# sed fails in a simple Makefile recipe

Tags: sed, makefile

I wrote a simple test.pc file as shown below:

```
includedir=/usr/include
includearchdir=/usr/include
```

All I want is to replace the */usr* with *${prefix}* so that it will become as shown below:

```
includedir=${prefix}/include
includearchdir=${prefix}/include
```

So, I wrote a simple Makefile to process the test.pc file as shown below:

```
all:
        sed -e 's|=/usr|=$\{prefix\}|g' test.pc
```

When I execute make, it processes the test.pc and shows the answer as follows with a missing **'$'** in *${prefix}*:

```
includedir={prefix}/include
includearchdir={prefix}/include
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in a Makefile, you need to escape the dollar sign `$`:

```
sed -e 's|=/usr|=$$\{prefix\}|g'
```

Make doesn't understand the quoting, so you need to escape characters even within the quoted string.

Comment: Thank you and it works on the simple Makefile file with the test.pc file. However, when I put this to a production Makefile, it doesn't work with a production .pc file, i.e. still has the missing dollar sign `$`. FYI, I am talking about the [https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/multimedia/imagemagick/Makefile](ImageMagick software package for OpenWRT) where I would like to add the ability to replace the `/usr` with `${prefix}` using sed in the `Build/InstallDev` section.

Comment: @Mazilo: Your link is broken.  Is what you're saying that I solved your question but your actual problem is something else?

Comment: My added sed line is `$(STAGING_DIR_HOST)/bin/sed -i 's|prefix=\(.*\)|prefix=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr|g;s|includearchdir=/usr|includearchdir=$$\{prefix\}|g' $(1)/usr/lib/pkgconfig/*.pc`

Comment: The problem I encountered is excerpted from an actual long Makefile. Instead of posting a long Makefile, I just excerpted the problem part to test and it exhibited the same problem. However, your answer fixes this problem to the Makefile I excerpted as shown in my OP. When I applied your fix to the actual long Makefile, it does not work and the `${prefix}` is still missing the dollar sign `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It turns out I need to use `$$$$\{prefix\}` instead of `$\{prefix\}` to replace the existing `/usr` in the production Makefile file. I don't know why, but it works So, my complete added line with a fix is shown below. Thank you everyone who helped and I appreciated.

```
$(STAGING_DIR_HOST)/bin/sed -i 's|prefix=\(.*\)|prefix=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr|g;s|includearchdir=/usr|includearchdir=$$$$\{prefix\}|g' $(1)/usr/lib/pkgconfig/*.pc
```

Comment: So basically Make was processing the string twice, so `$$$$` becomes `$$` then `$`.  Well, glad you got it sorted.